# Apache Tomcat RemoteIpValve Configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee

i am trying to configure RemoteIpValve in apache tomcat to restrict some IP dynamically when i found we are receiving coutinuous hits to our application,

i have seen many examples that showed how to configure list of ip statically
like  ,

can any one help me to add ip into deny list or to have DB Connection for this...